# Server crashed but why?

Tags: 14.04, server, kernel, kvm-virtualization, crash

could someone tell me what causes the crash of this kernel panic?

This machine (14.04.1) is a virtual machine on my KVM host (14.04.1)

See the screenshot [image: here]

My host machine has 32GB of RAM and uses ~20GB.

Comment: 64 or 32 bit? Does the host report any problems? IMHO related to the memory allocator...

Comment: 64Bit (VM and Host). The strange thing is some other machines also got crashes and my host also (~once a day).

Comment: In that case I suspect the host to be the cause... Anything in the logs (on the host)?

Comment: The problem is I don´t get any logs about the crashes, see here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/532442/14-04-kernel-panic

Comment: I don't think you need to look into the VMs if it's your **host** that crashes. How much memory does the host have?